# Getting SQL Exception while using Java's PreparedStatement for select query

Tags: java, db2, sqlexception

I have entered the query manually and by copy pasting, and it runs fine. When I make the query into a PreparedStatement Object I get an error:

`com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10145][10844][4.22.29] Invalid parameter 1: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815`

I have read the JavaDoc for PreparedStatement objects but am fresh out of ideas. My other queries that are identical (but use int instead of String) work fine. Any thoughts?

A snippet of the code:

```
      String queryText = "";
      PreparedStatement querySt = null; 
      ResultSet answers = null; 


      queryText = "SELECT title, year, language, weight FROM yrb_book WHERE title = '?' AND cat = '?' ";

      try 
      {
          querySt = DbConn.prepareStatement(queryText);
      } 
      catch(SQLException e) 
      {
          System.out.println(e);
          System.exit(0);
      }

      // Execute the query.
      try 
      {
          querySt.setString(1, title);
          querySt.setString(2, category);
          answers = querySt.executeQuery();
      }
```

Below is the table I am working with:
`create table yrb_book (
    title     varchar(25)  not null,
    year      smallint     not null,
    language  varchar(10),
    cat       varchar(10)  not null,
    weight    smallint     not null,
    constraint yrb_book_pk
        primary key (title, year),
    constraint yrb_book_fk_cat
        foreign key (cat) references yrb_category,
    constraint yrb_book_weight
        check (weight > 0)
);`

I studied this answer for 30 minutes, but cannot see how it can apply in my case.
[Getting SQL Exception while using prepared statement for select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399879/getting-sql-exception-while-using-prepared-statement-for-select-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use quotes (single and double) for token "?". Instead of:

```
queryText = "SELECT title, year, language, weight FROM yrb_book WHERE title = '?' AND cat = '?' ";
```

use:

```
queryText = "SELECT title, year, language, weight FROM yrb_book WHERE title = ? AND cat = ? ";
```

Comment: @ jplc you need the single quotes or it becomes a bad db2 query. I am trying to go more this way: `string temp = "'"+title+"'";`

Comment: @Mike did you execute the new query suggested. Java SQL API (PreparedStatement) do the job for you. If you get a new error then post it.

Comment: you are correct and I was wrong. Your suggestion fixed my problem. Thanks for your suggestion, I really appreciate it! Java indeed does add the `'` to strings when replacing the `?` on its own. Thanks again.